# How to get just the name of the file from a full directory filename?

Tags: c#, directory, filenames

I have a function which runs to insert a filename and a part number into a table. however the filename which gets inserted includes the whole directory e.g. c:\:folder\uploads\xml\file.xml

I would like just file.xml

```
string source = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/uploads/xml/");
        part retrun = null;
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(source);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(file));
            Stream reader = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            file f = (file)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            string part = "";
            foreach (part p in f.@class.part)
            {
                part = p.tcpn.ToString();
                XMLProductQueries.InsertIntoXMLProducts(context, fileName, part);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Path.GetFileName(fileName)` to extract the file name from your path.

```
Path.GetFileName(@"c:\:folder\uploads\xml\file.xml") // => returns file.xml
```